# Is it a bad idea to use SQLExecDirect with preformatted query string instead of SQLPrepare+SQLBindParameter+SQLExecute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-c++, odbc

OK, at the first glance, it seems that it must be more efficient to use `SQLPrepare`+`SQLBindParameter`+`SQLExecute` than format string (e.g. with `CString::Format`) and pass the whole complete query string to `SQLExecDirect`. If not, why would there exist the second method (`SQLPrepare`+`SQLBindParameter`+`SQLExecute`) at all?

BUT... here is what I think: The driver has sooner or later (I suspect later, but anyway...) convert the parameters (that I feed it with `SQLBindParameter`) into string representation right? (Or maybe not?) So if I make this formatting in my application (`printf`-like formatting), will I have any loss in performance?

One thing I suspect is that when the connection is over the network, passing parameters as raw data and then formatting them at server end might decrease the network traffic, instead of passing preformatted query strings, but lets ignore the network traffic for a moment. If not that, is there any performance gain in using `SQLPrepare`+`SQLBindParameter`+`SQLExecute` instead of formatting full query string in application and then using `SQLExecDirect`?

For me using `SQLExecDirect` is simpler and more convenient, so I need good answer on whether (and if) I should opt to another approach.

**Important**: If you will say that `SQLPrepare`+`SQLBindParameter`+`SQLExecute` approach will give better performance, I'd like to know **how much**! I don't mind theoretical assumptions, I'd like to know when is it worth practically? My current use-case is not very db-intensive, I won't have more than 100 inserts/updates per second, is it ok to use `SQLExecDirect`? In what scenarios - if ever - do I have to use `SQLPrepare`+`SQLBindParameter`+`SQLExecute`?

Comment: **No it's not... if the bindings are simple, queries are short and you know what you're doing.** Especially for short ones involving numbers *(like `select * from table where id=#;`)*. Ignore dogma *(answers below)* and use your head. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are inserting or updating with the same SQL (excluding parameters) repeatedly then SQLPrepare, SQLBindParameter and SQLExecute will be faster than SQLExecDirect every time. Consider:

```
SQLPrepare("insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(?,?);");
for (n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
    SQLBindParameter(1, n);
    SQLBindParameter(2, n);
    SQLExecute;
}
```

and

```
for (n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
    char sql[1000];
    sprintf("insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(%d,%d)", n, n);
    SQLExecDirect(sql);
}
```

In the first example, the statement is prepared once and hence the db engine only has to parse it once and work out an execution plan once. In the second example the sql and parameters are passed every time and the SQL looks different every time so it is parsed each time.

In addition, in the first example you can use arrays of parameters to pass multiple rows of parameters in one go - see SQL_PARAMSET_SIZE.

See [3.1.2 Inserting data](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_odbc_bridge/performance_white_paper.html#3_1_2) for a worked example and an indication of how much time you can save.

Ignore network traffic, you'll just be second guessing what happens under the hood in the driver.

ADDITION:
Regarding your description of what happens with parameters where you seem to think the driver will convert them to strings; the other advantage of binding parameters is you can provide them in one type and ask the driver to use them as another type. You may find you'll come across a parameter type which cannot easily be represented as a string without adding some sort of conversion function which could be avoided with a parameter.

Comment: No no no... I don't mean executing SQLExecDirect multiple times. The sprintf can be used in the loop for formatting the values part, and then appended to statement part ("insert into mytable (cola, colb) values..."), and then passed to single SQLExecDirect call.

Comment: You said "If not, why would there exist the second method" and I've pointed out the usage case for it. If you only ever call SQLExecDirect once you haven't got much to compare.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a bad idea, and for two reasons:

1. Performance

   SQLPrepare causes the SQL statement to be parsed, and depending on the SQL statement it can be time consuming. If you're using a DB on another server, it might get sent to it for parsing. Even if the parsing takes only e.g. 10% time of executing your whole query, you save that time when executing the statement twice. That may be the case when you're inserting multiple rows, or call a "select" another time.

   Of course the SQL statement passed must always be a static string. Some SQL frameworks may even do prepared statement caching for you. I don't know if ODBC does this. If you want to have real performance numbers, you have to measure for yourself - every query is different (and even might depend on the table contents, too).
2. SQL Injection

   No matter what you say where the data comes from that you're formatting with CString::Format or any other method, you might be at risk for SQL injection. Even if you're using strings from your sources, sometimes later you or someone other may be changing your code to accept data from outside, and then you're vulnerable to SQL injection. If you need more info about SQL injection, just search StackOverflow, I'm sure there are some good questions about it, or see this image: [image: http://xkcd.com/327/]

Comment: SQL Injection is a good point. However I don't fully get what you mean in first part (when you say "you save that time when executing the statement twice"). If you mean what **bohica** said, please view my comment on his reply.

Comment: I updated the "Performance" paragraph to clarify the meaning of executing the statement twice.